# App running fine on device on debug mode but crashing when I'm running it independently

Tags: ios

My app working fine on device on debug mode but as soon as I'm running my app without Mac or Xcode debug mode it getting crash.

Comment: with device connected you can look at the crash logs in Organizer window of Xcode. What do they tell you?

Comment: Hi Kai, 
Thanks for reply, but its not showing perfect when my device is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change Your provisioning profile to development type.